# Get value from variable created on run time from another variable in Oracle PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have this thing in unix for example below

```
filename1_temp=3
var1=filename1
var2=${var1}_temp
var3=\$${var2}
```

so basically var3 contains the value stored in variable filename1_temp which is 3. I need this implementation in oracle PL/SQL. For example

```
filename1_temp:=3
var1:="filename1";
var2:=var1||"_temp";
var3:=???
```

How will I do it in PL/SQL??

Please suggest.

Comment: You'd have to use dynamic sql to do such a thing, but typically in PL/SQL you wouldn't do this. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to get values from table using a variable which is passed through different applications. In unix we can handle that. In plsql dynamic query also i can use the value of var3 not value of filename1_temp.

Comment: so the value of filename1_temp is something that you want to pass in as a parameter into a PL/SQL procedure?

Comment: yes I want to use value of filename1_temp in dynamic sql. I have picked the column var1(filename1) from a table and appended "_temp" in their values. Now the values created(filename1_temp) I want to pass filename1_temp's value in next proc.

Comment: if all you're wanting to do is pass the value of a variable into PL/SQL as a parameter, then you probably don't need dynamic PL/SQL after all. It would really help if you could update your question with details on what you plan on doing with the value of the filename1_temp in PL/SQL. As in, "I want to insert the value of this variable into a table" or "I want to select from the tablename with the same name as the value", etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd like to evaluate a string as a PL/SQL code. Essentially the following code should do what you're asking but unfortunately it doesn't work:

```
declare
  filename1_temp constant varchar2(32767) := 'magic';
  var1 constant varchar2(32767) := 'filename1';
  var2 constant varchar2(32767) := var1 || '_temp';
  var3 varchar2(32767);
  function eval(p_var in varchar2) return varchar2 is
    v_ret varchar2(32767);
  begin
    execute immediate 'begin :ret := ' || p_var || '; end;'
      using out v_ret;
    return v_ret;
  end;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('var3 = ' || var3);
  var3 := eval(var2); -- expecting magic
  dbms_output.put_line('var3 = ' || var3);
end;
/
```

It fails with:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 15:
PLS-00201: identifier 'FILENAME1_TEMP' must be declared
```

because execute immediate runs in SQL context and it doesn't know the details of the anonymous PL/SQL block. So you have to make the variable accessible from SQL too. Here is an example where I have used public package variable:

```
create or replace package so49 is
  filename1_temp varchar2(32767);
end;
/
show errors

declare
  var1 constant varchar2(32767) := 'so49.filename1';
  var2 constant varchar2(32767) := var1 || '_temp';
  var3 varchar2(32767);
  function eval(p_var in varchar2) return varchar2 is
    v_ret varchar2(32767);
  begin
    execute immediate 'begin :ret := ' || p_var || '; end;'
      using out v_ret;
    return v_ret;
  end;
begin
  so49.filename1_temp := 'magic';
  dbms_output.put_line('var3 = ' || var3);
  var3 := eval(var2); -- expecting magic
  dbms_output.put_line('var3 = ' || var3);
end;
/
```

The magic happens:

```
SQL> @so49

var3 =
var3 = magic

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are looking for but do you want this kind of stuff..

```
declare
  filename1_temp number(4);
  var1           number(4);
  var2           varchar2(100);
  var3           varchar2(100);
begin
  filename1_temp := 3 ;
  var1 := filename1_temp;
  var2           := to_char(var1) || '_temp';
  var3           := var2;
  dbms_output.put_line(var3);
end;
```

Comment: but in output will print "3_temp". lets suppose 3_temp is variable define in declaration part.
3_temp:=4;
now we have var2 :=var3:='3_temp';
How we can use var3 or var2 so that we will obtain 4(which is value of 3_temp).